# HTML5 - database storage - can i access this from multiple websites?

Tags: database, html, local-storage

I'm wondering if I store some information in the html5  database storage engine and call it say dbtest, and then if I have another website with a different domain, can that website also access the data (presuming the same PC and browser)

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry.  You can access the database cross sub-domain (e.g. foo.domain1.com and bar.domain1.com), but not from different domains (TLDs).